# How make Gradle run single-threaded

Tags: gradle

I'm working with Gradle 8.2.1 + Java 17 on an ancient Ubuntu system. I'd like to figure out how to get Gradle to run without creating another thread or process.

Running `gradlew`, it stops after a few seconds with

```
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
```

With `gradlew <my-target> --no-daemon`, it says `To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked.` So apparently it is still creating a separate thread or process.

Is there any way to prevent Gradle, via `--no-daemon` or any other means, from creating another thread or process, and doing all of its tasks in one thread or process?

Searching the Internet, I found some indications, several years old at this point, that it might be impossible; and other indications, more recent, that it might be possible via JAVA_OPTS or something. I tinkered with it but wasn't able to figure out anything.

Comment: How old is your Ubuntu?  I don't think it's gradle - it may be Java crashing on an unsupported O/S.  If not, can't you compile on another machine and deploy to the ancient Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A web search shows the the "Gradle build daemon disappeared" has been encountered by a number of people with various systems, and some of them fairly recent, so on the face of it, it doesn't seem like the age of the system is at issue. Good idea about compiling on another system, I can do that. I'm still interested to know how to work around this problem if there are any more suggestions.